# Use regex get string "get this" in "adfadf[somestring] get-this adfaf" in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to get "`get-this`" without the blank around it.

```
String input = "adfa dfadf[somestring] get-this adfaf adfadfad adfajiojoij [somestring] dont-get-this ";
```

So basically I want to get the **first** string after the **first** paired square bracket.
Here's my regex but it doesn't work:

```
(?<=.*?\[.*?\]\p{Blank}).*?[\]^.*?\p{Blank}]
```

but if I change the ".*?" between square brackets into "somestring" it works.

Does anyone know why? Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider not using regex. ``String.indexOf("]")`` may be enough and it is considerable faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't use a quantifier like `*` or `*?` inside a lookbehind assertion in Java. Only limited quantifiers `{m,n}` are allowed in a lookbehind, so you can write your pattern in this way:

```
(?<=\[[^]]{1,1000}]\s{0,1000})\S+
```

or in a java string:

```
string pattern = "(?<=\\[[^]]{1,1000}]\\s{0,1000})\\S+";
```

pattern details:

```
(?<=               # open the lookbehind: preceded by...
    \[             # a literal [
    [^]]{1,1000}   # between one and 1000 characters that are not a ]
    ]              # literal ]
    \s{0,1000}     # between zero and 1000 white-spaces
)                  # close the lookbehind
\S+                # one or more characters that are not white-spaces
```

Note that the lookbehind is only a test and all that is described inside will not be included in the whole match result.

Depending what you are trying to do, It is possible the lookbehind isn't needed at all and that you can simply use a capture group for the same result:

```
\[[^]]+]\s*(\S+)
```

pattern details:

```
\[          # a literal [
[^]]+       # one or more characters that are not a ]
]           # a literal ]
\s*         # zero or more white-spaces
(           # open the capture group 1
    \S+     # all that is not a white-space
)           # close the capture group 1
```

When this pattern succeeds, two results are returned: the whole match (as the previous pattern) and the capture group 1 (the part enclosed between parenthesis). The capture group is a convenient way to extract particular parts of a larger pattern. 
Then you only need to extract the capture group 1 to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. The first one it returned to me includes `[somestring]`, the second one is what I want.

Comment: @Zip: What do you call the *"first one"*?

Comment: The first result `\[[^]]+]\s*(\S+)` returns me.

Comment: @Zip: as explained in the post, what you call "the second one" is the content of the capture group.

Comment: I see, can you explain the logic to me? I'm very new to regex.

Comment: @Zip: I will add descriptions for the two patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense to me. So it's not really possible to get only group(1) answer with a single regex?

Comment: Use the first pattern to do that since all the content in the lookbehind is excluded from the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\[somestring\] )(\S*)(?= )
```

will get the "get this".

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/sB5mX1/2) for a demo.

In Java:

```
String str = "somestring";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[" + str + "\\] )(\\S*)(?= ))";
```

Comment: This works thanks. But I would need the string that after [somestrhing] not a string that surrounded by space, sorry for the bad example.

Comment: Do you know some method so that I don't have to use "somestring" in the regex because I won't be able to know what is exactly that string?